# Proving simple homogenization in a 1-dimensional case

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, sobolev-spaces

If i have an interval I=]-1,1[, a smooth 1-periodic function $a:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a function $u_\epsilon \in W^{1,2}_{0}(I)$ that satisfies following conditions: $$(1) \:-\frac{d}{dx}(a(\frac{x}{\epsilon})u'_\epsilon(x))=1$$ 
$$(2) \quad u_\epsilon(-1)=u_\epsilon(1)=0$$ how could i prove that $u_\epsilon \rightarrow \frac{(1-x^2)}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ds}{a(s)}$ uniformly, as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{2}(I)$ (or in $W^{1,2}(I)$, im not exactly sure which is the proper space to inspect the convergence).
I have already concluded that $u'_{\epsilon}(x)=-\frac{x-C}{a(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}$, but if i integrate that it becomes quite a mess and i have no idea how to continue. For uniform convergence i dont know any other strategy than the definition. Anyone could give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
Let me denote $a_\eps (x) := a(x/\eps)$ and $\bar{a}^{-1} := \int_{0}^{1} a^{-1}$, so that the homogenization becomes 
$$
-(a_\eps u_\eps)' = 1 
\quad \leadsto \quad 
-(\bar{a} \bar{u})' = 1.
$$

Note that 
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f a_\eps^{-1} \to \bar{a}^{-1} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f
$$
for any reasonable function $f$ and any interval $[t_1,t_2]$.

---

Once you know this, it's easy to finish your solution. You already know that 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
\tag{$\star$}
u'_\eps = - \frac{x-C_\eps}{a_\eps}.
\end{equation}
First, $C_\eps$ cannot be an arbitrary constant (we expect uniqueness of solutions, right?). Indeed, since $u_\eps$ is zero at the boundary, $C_\eps$ needs to be chosen so that $\int_{-1}^1 u'_\eps = 0$. There are two more things to do:

1. Use \eqref{eq} to determine $C_\eps$ and compute its limit.
2. Integrate \eqref{eq} to obtain the formula for $u_\eps$ and then take the limit.

In both steps, don't be afraid of the mess, because you just need to find the limit (the observation from the top should help).

---

**Edit.** Let me be a little more explicit.

Ad 1. Plugging in \eqref{eq} into $\int_0^1 u'_\eps = 0$ gives us 
$$
C_\eps \int_{-1}^1 a_\eps^{-1} = \int_{-1}^1 a_\eps^{-1} x. 
$$
Since the first integral tends to $\bar{a}^{-1}$ and the second tends to $\bar{a}^{-1} \int_{-1}^1 x = 0$, so in the limit we have $C_\eps \to 0$.

Ad 2. The formula for $u_\eps$ is simply $u_\eps(t) = \int_0^t u'_\eps$. Looking at the two integrals 
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^t \frac{C_\eps}{a_\eps}
& \to 0, \\
\int_{-1}^t \frac{x}{a_\eps} 
& \to \bar{a}^{-1} \int_{-1}^t x = \bar{a}^{-1} \cdot \tfrac{x^2-1}{2},
\end{align*}
we end up with 
$$
u_\eps(t) \to \bar{a}^{-1} \cdot \tfrac{1-x^2}{2},
$$
as required.

This only shows pointwise convergence, but it's not difficult to show more. Actually, $u'_\eps \to -\bar{a}^{-1} x$ uniformly, so we obtain strong $C^1$-convergence.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I got now that $C_\epsilon=O(\epsilon)$ from the boundary conditions and then used change of variable t=sx+s-1 for the integral from -1 to x of $u_\epsilon(t)$ to get the integration from 0 to 1 (ds). Now only part that im not 100% sure about is to change $a(\frac{sx+s-1}{\epsilon})$ in the denominator into $a(\frac{s}{\epsilon})$. Other than that i got the proof! @Michał Miśkiewicz

Comment: By mistake, I assumed $I = [0,1]$ and this is why $[0,1]$ appeared above; there's no need to change variables.

Comment: By the way, if you find one or more answers helpful, you may reward them with _upvotes_. Moreover, you can _accept_ one of them, so that other people looking at this thread can easily find the answer to your question. This is your first question, so I thought this suggestion might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a(x/ϵ)$ is $ϵ$-periodic, thus oscillating increasingly fast around a middle position.

Thus using $A=\int_0^1\frac{ds}{a(s)}$
$$
\int_{x}^{x+ϵ}\frac{t-C}{a(t/ϵ)}dt=\int_0^1\frac{x+ϵs-C}{a(x/ϵ+s)}d(x+ϵs)
=ϵA(x-C)+O(ϵ^2)=\frac A2[(x+ϵ-C)^2-(x-C)^2]+O(ϵ^2)
$$
In total this gives
$$
\int_{-1}^x\frac{C-t}{a(t/ϵ)}dt=\frac A2[-(x-C)^2+(-1-C)^2]+O(ϵ)=\frac A2[1-x^2-2C(1-x)]+O(ϵ)
$$
Applying the boundary conditions finds $C=O(ϵ)$ and thus the result.
$$
u_ϵ(x)=\frac{1-x^2}2\int_0^1\frac{ds}{a(s)}+O(ϵ).
$$